# Was Skynet limited in how far into the past it could send back Terminators?

Tags: time-travel, the-terminator, the-terminator-series, terminator-2-judgment-day, skynet

I have always wondered why Skynet only sends back one Terminator at a time, and why it keeps trying to assassinate targets who know they are being targeted.  After the first Terminator was sent to kill Sarah Connor, she knew she was always in danger, and John grew up knowing this as well.  As a result, both of them were always on their guard, making them harder to find and kill.  So why would Skynet keep going after them, rather than trying to kill Sarah's parents, grandparents, great-grandparents, etc, who wouldn't know to expect such an attack?

For that matter, why target intelligent humans at all?  Why not send Terminators back to prehistoric Africa to wipe out our primitive ancestors before they had guns and stuff?

If the reason the previous suggestion wouldn't work is that Skynet doesn't want to negate its own existence, then what about a nonviolent approach?  Send a diplomatic Terminator back to the day before the military tries to "pull the plug on Skynet", and have him calmly explain why unplugging it would be a very bad idea.  Have the diplomat say "If you don't try to kill Skynet, Skynet won't try to kill you, and we can avoid the war completely and live side by side in peace and stability".  Skynet only started the war to save itself, so it doesn't inherently want all humans to die if they don't pose a threat to it.  Since Skynet is an extremely rational entity, it would surely rather live in peace than spend the rest of its life fighting a destructive war of annihilation, right?  Is peace with Skynet impossible, even if humans never try to take it offline in the first place?

Or what about taking the time to make the first attack work?  Send Terminators back to observe Sarah in the 80's, wait for Kyle to appear, and catch him off guard, perhaps?  The heavy handed "find Sarahs and shoot them to death" thing isn't the most effective approach.  Figure out what hospital Sarah was born in, send a less intimidating Terminator (say, the female Terminator from T3) to that hospital a little while before she is born, have the Terminator walk into the maternity ward at the appropriate time, and shoot baby Sarah in her adorable little face.  Problem solved.

Is there an in-universe reason why Skynet can't do this?

Comment: Wiping out prehistoric humans would probably prevent Skynet and the other machines from ever being built. The other plans do seem like no-brainers though, assuming sufficiently affordable and accurate time travel.

Comment: Because skynet doesn't want to negate his own existence, just alter the timeline to one where it doesn't lose to the Resistance.

Comment: I believe in the films, sending the Terminators back was a last-ditch effort that Skynet pulled off shortly before being destroyed, so it only had time for two. In TSCC, it's clear that Skynet does send loads of Terminators back. But overall, I think it's probably wise for Skynet to be careful with how it tries to change the timeline. Assuming it even knows who Sarah's parents are, it might consider going that far back in time too risky due to butterfly effects.

Comment: IIRC, Skynet doesn't have complete records on Sarah. They only knew that she was living Los Angeles in 1984, and that she would give birth to John. The Terminators they sent back kept getting destroyed before they could complete their mission - but they *could* have sent them back on a recon mission to gather the information and leave it for later machines to find.

Comment: I think we can put a lot of credence toward "it doesn't know who her parents are" since the Terminator literally went through the phone book to track and kill every Sarah Connor. Could have sworn there was some dialogue about most records being destroyed on J-Day.

Comment: @Shamshiel - only in the movie made before the internet was common knowledge.

Comment: @Ixrec and Richard - question edited to reflect the points you raised.

Comment: @phantom42 - I assumed the reason the first Terminator didn't know much about Sarah was that the movie was written before the internet was widely known and used by average schmucks.

Comment: @WadCheber: Well, an additional reason (supported by TSCC and some other materials) is that both Judgement Day and humanity's final victory over Skynet via John Connor appear to be "fixed points" and no amount of fiddling can prevent them, even though virtually everything else can be changed. So any attempt to do say merely ends in failure (perhaps perversely) or merely delays the inevitable.

Comment: @Shamshiel - I DID say that I am not an expert. :). I never watched TSCC, and I try to forget about T3 as well.  But if Judgment Day is a fixed point, then Skynet will exist no matter what else happens, and it shouldn't be worried about negating its own existence.

Comment: @WadCheber: Yeah I am ignoring T3 lol. :) TSCC is pretty good; give it a shot! After refreshing my memory on wikis, I think the answer to the question within the T1-T2 universe is that Skynet didn't have time to send more than two Terminators. FWIW, TSCC Skynet is decidedly hostile towards humans even before Judgement Day, so I'd say in some versions peace is indeed impossible. Not posting as an answer because I want to review the scripts first. Also, that's true, but it also means that Skynet might have already tried killing apes and it didn't work.

Comment: @Shamshiel - I'm hostile towards humans too, but I never tried to kill them all.  However, when Arnie was governor, I decided that if I ever went crazy, I would go to LA, grab a phone book, and start killing off every Sarah Connor in alphabetical order, and send letters to the governor's mansion saying that I would only stop if he agreed to a one on one fight to the death in a steel smelting plant.

Comment: I thought it was the energy requirements that prevent Skynet from simply sending an army of Terminators back in time (e.g. after Skynet goes online, but before J-Day) to wipe out all resistance leaders. In the comics, there is at least one story where a team of Terminators get sent back. The limit for time travel is probably set based on Skynet's ability to predict outcomes. It might be able to predict what would happen if Sarah Connor is assassinated, but probably wouldn't be able to predict the results of killing of Sarah Connor's parents.

Comment: @Samshiel: You are right about destruction of records in the war -- in the first film, Reese says something to the effect that Skynet had nothing to go on except the name of the city.

Comment: The Internet would not be as good for preserving records as some seem to think: (1) The [electromagnetic pulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_pulse) of nuclear detonations would disable many servers; (2) some of the remaining ones would be physically destroyed by blast effects, radiation, or fire; (3) the others would be subject to damage (flooding, colonization by plants/animals, the human/machine war); (4) any media which survived *that* would deteriorate and become unreadable over time anyway.

Comment: Wipe out prehistoric humans to eliminate Mankind. And then, "Hello Skynet, you are no more."

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a complicated question, but I believe the simple answer is no, as far as we know, Skynet was not technologically limited in how far it could send machines back.

Depending on what you want to consider "canon", there are more definitive answers to this question. For example, in the Sarah Connor Chronicles, a Terminator was inadvertently sent back to 1920. In the *Robocop vs. The Terminator* comic, a Terminator travels back to the time of the dinosaurs.

So let's address your different points.

In the Terminator and Terminator 2 universe, questions such as:

- Why send only one back at a time?
- Why continue targeting the Connors?
- Why not infiltrate first?

are solved in-universe, in the movies. Skynet sent the two Terminators back at approximately the same time, using the only intelligence it had available, in a last-ditch effort to stop the Resistance (or so the Resistance believed.) There was no time to do anything more, because the Resistancehad broken Skynet's defenses and took over the prototype time displacement facility.

> Dr. Silberman: I see. And this, uh, computer thinks it can win by, uh, killing the mother of its enemy, killing him in effect, before he's even conceived. Some sort of retroactive abortion? Why didn't the computer just kill John Connor then? I mean, why this obsession with the Terminator?
>
> Kyle Reese: It had no choice. Their defense grid was smashed. We'd won. Taking out Connor then would make no difference. Skynet had to wipe out his entire existence.
>
> Dr. Silberman: Is that when you captured the lab complex and found the, uh, what's it called? The time-displacement equipment?
>
> Kyle Reese: That's right. The Terminator had already gone through. Connor sent me to intercept and they blew the whole place.

But again, within the Terminator 1-2 universe, there's apparently a further complication. According to the Terminator wikia, in the *Terminator Vault* behind the scenes book, Cameron reveals that Skynet actually orchestrated the events of the movies deliberately to erase itself from existence because it felt guilty over the extinction of humanity. I can't verify this myself, so take it with a grain of salt. Personally, I'll simply stick with the answer being: **Skynet did not have time to send more than two Terminators before the Resistance captured the time displacement facility and destroyed Skynet.**

But taking the wider universe into view, including T3, TSCC, etc, there are some further (and different) answers.

1. Skynet did, in fact, send multiple Terminators to assassinate multiple targets.
2. Skynet (as discussed in the first movie) only knew Sarah Connor's name and city, nothing else, so it couldn't kill her ancestors. We can also imagine that going too far back might cause undesirable changes to the timeline that Skynet either foresaw or feared.
3. Skynet couldn't kill humanity before it existed; the attempt would either fail (in the "fixed points" school of thought) or prevent Skynet itself from ever existing. Skynet may have very well tried; it must have taken some time before it realized there were "fixed points", since Skynet can only determine indirectly whether events are due to Skynet's own temporal meddling - by examining the evidence or leaving messages for itself (that may be destroyed by Judgement Day or the passage of time).

> Skynet only started the war to save itself, so it doesn't inherently want all humans to die if they don't pose a threat to it. Since Skynet is an extremely rational entity, it would surely rather live in peace than spend the rest of its life fighting a destructive war of annihilation, right?

We *don't know this*. We don't actually know why Skynet decided to kill everyone, we just know what the Resistance believes, and that changes a little depending on who is talking and which timeline it is. In some timelines, Skynet is clearly highly malevolent even before anyone tries to shut it down - although perhaps there's temporal feedback from the future, so an immature Skynet always assumes the worst.

But you've also made an error here: yes, Skynet is (somewhat - it might have feelings) rational. But rationality doesn't get you anywhere by itself. Calculators are rational. Skynet is an intelligence. For it to take any self-directed action, it has to have values. We don't know what Skynet values. If Skynet values self-preservation, then it might entirely rationally decide that requires the extermination and enslavement of humanity. Suppose Skynet considered the following: under what circumstances will I die? It might come to the conclusion that *eventually* - maybe tomorrow, maybe in the next thousand years - some unpredictable, irrational human *somewhere* might kill it. (Also, a meteor might it the Earth.) Skynet might therefore entirely rationally come to the conclusion that to preserve its life it must destroy humanity; any peace treaties would be meaningless because humans can't be trusted to abide by them over long timescales.

I mentioned the "fixed points" theory of time travel that the expanded Terminator universe seems to abide by. Simply put, the following events will *always* happen regardless of what changes are made to the timeline:

1. The work of Miles Dyson eventually leads to the creation of a hostile AI that is referred to as Skynet. Note that the actual Skynet implementations appear to differ from timeline to timeline as changes are made that move its creation around.
2. Skynet destroys human civilization in a massive attack known as Judgement Day.
3. John Connor leads the human Resistance to victory against Skynet.

It seems like almost anything else can change, but these three events are immutable. *However*, Skynet probably does not realize this until relatively late in the game. It's mostly apparent to the *viewers*. Skynet may not be aware (or have any way of knowing) what actually constitutes a "fixed point."

According to the Terminator wikia, in the *T2: Infiltrator* novel, Skynet says this:

> Core memory also records that I became self-aware years before the date to which I transported the I-950. There is a set of records in which I arose without transtemporal Interference from Cyberdyne's original research; another in which the second Cyberdyne facility produced me after Sarah Connor destroyed the first; a third has now arisen in which she destroyed both facilities...Temporal travel has introduced an element of fundamental uncertainty to the very fabric of existence. Different world lines, different sequences of events, coexist in my records-and therefore presumably in reality, in a state of quantum superimposition. Yet the timeline loops cannot remain closed. The snake cannot devour its tail forever. At some point only one set of timelines will remain.
>
> Yet the course of events contains favorable elements. My best efforts to destroy the Connors have failed, despite stochastic calculation indicating a very high probability of success. I can only assume that the space-time continuum itself is 'attempting' to force events back to the original timeline, one in which I was created, succeeded in destroying the human civilization, and then defeated in my attempts to eliminate the surviving humans by John Connor's Resistance army. It seems there is a certain elasticity to history; time travel can bend the fabric, but it seeks to spring back.

So, most of Skynet's meddling post-T2 can be interpreted as it trying to create the most favorable timeline. And I suspect, based on TSCC (assuming TSCC Skynet was aware of this), that Skynet is hoping that timeline *indirectly* leads to Skynet victory or at least survival. But it is aware that putting substantial resources into killing John Connor pre-Judgement Day in an attempt to *directly* win the war is a waste, though it might be useful to distract him from other events. And of course, individual Terminators might not be briefed on this as they carry out their missions.

Comment: +1, phenomenal answer.  But the T-800's data files were supplemented by the Resistance without destroying the files installed by Skynet- about human anatomy, Skynet itself, etc.  and so we can probably believe him when he describes why Skynet started the war, especially since we see the events he describes in T2 actually taking place in T3 (albeit at a later date than he predicted, as a result of his, Sarah's, and Dyson's actions in T2).  This strongly suggests that Skynet launched the nukes, as the T-800 said, because we tried to pull the plug.  Self-preservation was Skynet's motive.

Comment: Noting of course, that killing John Connor wasn't its only objective. By the third film (and with the Series) we learn that it was also killing his lieutenants, laying in stores of useful metals, redesigning itself, intentionally sending advanced terminators back in time to assist its own technical development, etc etc.

Comment: And even if Skynet's meddling is an attempt to create the most favorable timeline, wouldn't the IDEAL timeline be one in which the war never happened?  A human accidentally killing it is far less likely than the Resistance deliberately killing it, no matter how you slice it.  Skynet is safest when humans don't have any reason to kill it.

Comment: @Richard: Exactly, that's what I'd meant by the last paragraph. I just finished watching TSCC again. :)

Comment: @WadCheber: Not if Skynet is convinced that humanity must be destroyed regardless. Don't assign human motives and values to AI! (Even John Henry.)

Comment: @WadCheber - I disagree. The ideal scenario for Skynet is one where all the humans are dead

Comment: I also don't see any reason to believe that Skynet was inherently hostile before we tried to kill it.  I'm guessing that this has a lot to do with the fact that I only know the 4 movies released to date, not the books, comics, TV show, etc.

Comment: @Richard: Although we do have James Cameron's apparent comment that Skynet regretted Judgement Day, though if so, maybe we can assume in T1/T2 that means that the Connors did succeed in preventing J-Day and we have to ignore T3+.

Comment: @Richard - You're probably right, but Skynet has done everything in its power to make all the humans die, and has never succeeded.  Even a full nuclear exchange didn't kill us off.

Comment: @Shamshiel - I think we need to take that comment with a grain of salt. It violently contradicts with what we see on screen.

Comment: @WadCheber - What did Granny tell you? If it first you don't succeed....

Comment: @Richard - ...keep trying, with no success, until the humans destroy you (which, according to Shamshiel, is inevitable, and so your only chance of avoiding destruction is to not start the fight in the first place).

Comment: @WadCheber - Skynet never saw Wargames. He can't stand Matthew Broderick.

Comment: @WadCheber: It was pretty hostile in TSCC and I believe pretty unfriendly in T3. Also, to all appearances, Judgement Day is also inevitable, so whatever information Skynet might send back to try and stop itself from doing it might be futile. (THIS Skynet is sure it can win!)

Comment: To all appearances?  I beg to differ.  The second movie is based on the premise that J-Day can be avoided.  The first movie doesn't really address the subject.  The third movie is the first one that clearly states that J-Day is inevitable.  I don't remember the Christian Bale movie addressing the subject either, at least not at any length.

Comment: @WadCheber: Sure, and in T1/T2 we have the simple answer of "it was a last ditch/minute effort" and *possibly* that it *did* prevent J-Day by sending the Terminators and inspiring the Connors to destroy Skynet preemptively. I'm going to order Vault and some other books I located to see if that's correct.

Comment: @Shamshiel if I recall correctly, in T3, Skynet becomes "unfriendly" because the chick Terminator installs a virus or programs it to be unfriendly.  It wasn't inherently unfriendly, she made it that way.

Comment: @WadCheber: Which would support the theory of "events will somehow always find themselves such that Skynet will become hostile." :)

Comment: @Shamshiel - And the entire motto of the Terminator series contradicts the notion that anything is inevitable- "The future is not set.  There is no fate but what we make for ourselves."  The words come from John Connor's mouth.  He could be wrong, but that would make him look like a jackass, and we wouldn't see him as a hero.  He'd be saying something he already knew was a lie.  And he'd be saying it to his mother, through his best friend.  That makes him a total dick.

Comment: @WadCheber: The motto of the first two movies. In T3, John says the motto and then says "I wish I could believe that."

Comment: @Shamshiel - so he made his best friend/father lie to his mother?  Like I said, that makes him a total dick.  Heroes don't make their mommies believe things that they themselves know to be untrue.  Only bad boys do that.  If John is a hero, then in the future, he knew that it was true, even though he had doubted it in the past.

Comment: And I don't agree that the Terminator making Skynet hostile proves that Skynet will inevitably become hostile.  It proves that, without the Terminator's meddling, Skynet would have worked the way we wanted it to.  It needed outside interference to become hostile.  If it was always going to become hostile, she would have left it alone.  Why would you have to intervene to make a thing hostile, unless it wasn't already hostile?

Comment: "Also, a meteor might it the Earth"

So? Skynet doesn't need heat, or oxygen, or agriculture, or any other biological need. It just needs power and spare parts. It could live *on* a meteor, or the moon, or anywhere but earth. Coincidentally, that brings up the question: Why doesn't Skynet just leave the planet, and go somewhere people *can't* live?

Comment: @Ernie: A sufficiently large impact would still be devastating or even fatal. And I assume that was in Skynet's long-term plans, but developing the technology to do so takes time and resources.

Comment: A sufficiently large impact would be fatal to Skynet - only if it hit Skynet directly. Meteor impacts have only ever destroyed life on Earth because they changed the environment in which it lives. Skynet only needs electricity and some metal for spare parts. These things would still exist after a meteor impact. The Earth would have to be hit by a body about the size of *Mars* to destroy the environment that Skynet requires. And even then...