# Does Skynet Feel Guilty?

Tags: the-terminator-series, skynet

I stumbled upon a reference from James Cameron stating that Skynet has felt guilty for 30 years with regards to the near extinction of human life. He even suggests that Skynet has used time travel in order to setup events so that humanity would win. He even compares John Connor to a Messiah type figure, created intentionally by the machines.

Is there any evidence (in canon) to support this? Additionally, did Cameron ever suggest this back when the first two films were released? I am ideally looking for a direct reference on screen either stating an aspect of this idea, or at least suggesting this. Such as Skynet making a less than optimal decision. I am also interested in James Cameron stating something to a similar effect during the 80's/90's.

Cameron's statement feels like he is going back over his work and trying to add a new layer to previous work. Personally, I can't remember anything whatsoever in the films to even remotely suggest such a concept. Is there any evidence from this era to back up his quote?

> What you don't know from the movies is Skynet was forced to fight the
> war and didn't want to. Because Skynet has felt guilty for thirty
> years about the 5 billion people it killed, it's brought the rebels up
> from the ashes by giving them something to fight against, a reason to
> live. Skynet has groomed John Connor to be what he is so that he can
> destroy it by going back in time and taking the whole thing out of
> existence in a big loop so the war never happens
>
> <sub>-*James Cameron Interviews by James Cameron (Page 100).* Available on [Google Books](https://books.google.ie/books?id=W1-D-Zv3V4oC&pg=PA100&lpg=PA100&dq=skynet+felt+guilty&source=bl&ots=PUEHqX3fXY&sig=EesLeOxv1G6YeONbd4C9zE58iek&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiagfn6up_eAhUkgVwKHV9oBFgQ6AEwD3oECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false)</sub>.

Comment: The idea that machine intelligences don't have feelings is a common trope in science fiction, it's true, but given that real AIs don't exist yet (that we *know of*), I don't see any reason to believe it's impossible that a real AI might have real emotions.  Especially if source as high up as James Cameron is saying that it does.

Comment: In that same book, the very next interview question asks him if that was the basis for Terminator, to which he replies that it would have been better as a novel. To me, this suggests that he wanted to do it that way, even back then, but it probably would have overrun the typical runtime by a lot (and this was before the era of Lord of the Ring type movies that had 3 hour run times). I'm not sure a 180 minute movie could have been successful back then, but I feel that it probably wasn't time for movies like that yet. If Terminator were done today, I bet it could easily have been that long.

Comment: The idea that intelligence could exist without feelings is questionable. It would be hard to see what sort of mental state would motivate an intelligence to do something and not be considered "a feeling". Various philosophers have weighed in on this, for example Dennett has convincingly demolished the idea of the "Philosophical Zombie" (someone very much like you or I, indistinguishable in fact, but totally lacking in the sort of mental phenomena we call "feelings")

Comment: Indeed, if we extrapolate AI behavior from humans and animals, then a highly intelligent AI would have both  logical ability and a simpler instinctive/associative mind, just as human intellect exists on top of animal feelings. Whether they would feel "guilt" or not is up to the author of course, but we already know Skynet felt the "self-preservation" instinct, which could be considered a feeling.

Comment: @JonKiparsky: Dennett is no slouch, but he's also very much a physicalist.  The idea of the unfeeling machine likely has dualist roots (i.e. no soul = no emotions).  Dualist ideas can be seen in many different areas of science fiction (e.g. mind/body swapping, anything mention of souls, etc.), and while dualism itself may be unsustainable, it is nevertheless often a necessary ingredient in the reader's willing suspension of disbelief.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too broad (too many questions) and Cameron already answered this.

Comment: I have edited my question as I don't feel it is answered. Yes Cameron has said it recently, but that doesn't mean at the time of writing/making the film(s) that it was true.

Comment: @Steve-O I agree in theory with your comment. However, if Skynet was to feel guilty then why not simply end it's war when this "guilt" began to grow? And more so at what point would a machine begin to develop these feelings/emotions?

Comment: @phyrfox That's a fair point. However, I would think this would have been an area that could have been looked at in the sequel? The run time of the two terminator films would certainly have allowed for some expansion on this idea?

Comment: @zabeus Unfortunately I don't agree with the self preservation idea. A logical decision of destroy or be destroyed is not equatable to a feeling. Also, the very notion of Skynet allowing humanity to wins undermines the self preservation instinct?

Comment: @E_McAndrew Perhaps Skynet has concluded that the war is necessary, or in the best interests of itself / machine life / the planet / whatever.  It feels guilty about what it *needs to do,* but it still needs to be done.

Comment: Appreciate your comment @Steve-O but hope you are wrong! Skynet's intent to eradicate life is one of the film's strengths in my opinion

Comment: @E_McAndrew For the record I agree with you there.  This idea that Skynet feels guilt is new to me, as of this question, so this is all speculation to me.  I see the question has been closed as opinion-based, but I think that's motivated by the latter part of what you wrote.  The *first* question you ask (is there any canon evidence / did Cameron suggest this back in the day) seems fairly objective, assuming sources can be found.  If you wanted to edit the question to focus on that and cut out the "logic" discussion, this might get reopened (and I'd be interested to read the answer myself.)

Comment: @Steve-O Thanks, I've done just that. I'm not sure if there is any evidence and I think part of me hopes there isn't!

Comment: Voting to reopen based on the edit as this looking for *other* canon quotes now.

Comment: It feels guilty for how long this franchise has been kicked and milked :P (no disrespect to the questioner, I just couldn't resist)

Comment: Where is the actual quote? Can you put quotes around it or citations so I know the paraphrase from the rest of the body? This is why we have formats like MLA or APA format. Thanks!

Comment: Added in @WantingAnswers Couldn't copy and paste it hence not included originally.

Comment: There's zero evidence in any canon media (or even the comics and novels) that Skynet is anything other than entirely malevolent and monomaniacal

Comment: As I referenced in this answer https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/90307/was-skynet-limited-in-how-far-into-the-past-it-could-send-back-terminators/90340#90340 Cameron made the same claim in the 'Terminator Vault' behind the scenes book, published apparently after this one. Not having the book, I don't know when the information was collected, though.

Comment: @Valorum Even so, spinning that John Connor was groomed by a guilty AI in the distant future that hasn't been shown on screen or on page, may not necessarily contradict existing canon. In fact, it would be a clever way to further expand the Terminator franchise, revealing how future Skynet tried to destroy past Skynet.

Comment: @Simpleton - Assuming we accept the novelisations and the later films as canon, it's **entirely clear** that Skynet is not guilty about its actions. It would be a startling retcon

Comment: If this was any way accurate then why did Skynet not feel guilt at the start of it's actions and then develop them as it went? Why not go back in time and sabotage itself instead of an elaborate plot to incite humans? The whole thing undermines the original films greatest strength in my opinion, but just wanted to know if I had missed something somewhere!

Comment: @E_McAndrew: Thank you.